# Fastcgi + nginx - web service not respone

Tags: c#, web-services, nginx, mono

I try to configure nginx server with fastcgi to provide my web service.

First I try web service by using:

> xsp --port 9000

Everyting was good. I go to localhost:9000/Payment.asmx and I test.

Then I try do use fastcgi - I configure everyting like here

http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx

And then I go to localhost:1234/Payment.asmx and I try test method and here is my problem. Each method always return "-0" and I don't know what it is, because in xsp --port it is working good.

Any idea? I have mono 3.2.3 and xsp-master

Comment: return "-0"? you need to be more clear on that one

Comment: Web service return "0 - " when response for call. All calls return the same value "0 - ".